# How can I change the QStyle properties in PyQt4?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I'd like to change the `QStyle::PM_TabBarTabHSpace` property for a PyQt application.  I read the [Qt document for QStyle](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#StyleHint-enum), but I'm not sure how to set this correctly in PyQt.

Non-working code:

```
style = QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks')
style.PM_TabBarTabHSpace = 5  # 5 pixels?
app.setStyle(style)
```

This code runs, but it doesn't change the padding on the tabbar tabs.  I tried using stylesheets to change the tabbar padding, but that ruins the graphics drawing, so that none of the default look-feel stuff gets drawn (I don't want to reimplement all the ui drawing).

I think I might need to use [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qproxystyle.html), but I can't find any examples of how to use this in PyQt4.  *Edit:* It seems that PyQt doesn't have QProxyStyle, as `from PyQt4.QtGui import QProxyStyle` fails.

Can someone please post an example of changing the value of `PM_TabBarTabHSpace`?  Thanks.

**Edit** Here is a skeleton code.  Changing the PM_TabBarTabHSpace value doesn't do anything. :(

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QTabWidget, QWidget,
                         QStyle, QStyleFactory)

def myPixelMetric(self, option=None, widget=None):
    if option == QStyle.PM_TabBarTabHSpace:
        return 200 # pixels
    else:
        return QStyle.pixelMetric(option, widget)

style = QStyleFactory.create('Windows')
style.pixelMetric = myPixelMetric

app = QApplication('test -style Cleanlooks'.split())
# Override style
app.setStyle(style)

tab = QTabWidget()
tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'one')
tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'two')
tab.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Doc for PyQt is here : http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qstyle.html

Comment: I've read the doc, but I'm still unsure of how to set `PM_TabBarTabHSpace`.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Also, the doc only provides C examples, and no Python examples.  Does this have to be done in C?

Comment: I don't know Python well, but I'm almost sure the problem is in the way you're overriding style.pixelMetric. I don't think your implementation of pixelMetric is getting called by Qt. Have you tried deriving from QStyle and providing a pixelMetric implementation in your derived class?

Comment: Also, the `style.PM_TabBarTabHSpace = 5` snippet won't work simply because QStyle doesn't have a public property "PM_TabBarTabHSpace". Your second code snippet where you try to override pixelMetric is the right approach.

Comment: I have problems deriving from QStyle because I need to implement all of the QStyle methods (which I don't know how to do properly).  I would rather derive from QCleanlooksStyle or QWindowsStyle, and only override pixelMetric, but PyQt doesn't provide QCleanlooksStyle or QWindowsStyle classes.

Comment: `styleClass = QApplication.style().__class__; class MyStyle(styleClass): ...` and you can override the `pixelMetric`

Answer (score 4):

QStyle.pixelMetric(...) is built-in class method. You can not set via function pointing. Because, it is in C code. You can test it with adding

```
def myPixelMetric(self, option=None, widget=None):
    print 'Debug, i am calling'
    ...
```

in your myPixelmetric function. You need to subclass Style object to achieve this. Here is an example:

```
class MyStyle(QCommonStyle):
    def pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, QStyleOption_option=None, QWidget_widget=None):
        if QStyle_PixelMetric == QStyle.PM_TabBarTabHSpace:
            return 200
        else:
            return QCommonStyle.pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, QStyleOption_option, QWidget_widget)


app = QApplication('test -style Cleanlooks'.split())
app.setStyle(MyStyle())
```

This code snippet will work, but it is ugly. I prefer using stylesheets over manipulating Style.